# What does the interface Comparable compare in Java?

Tags: java, compareto

I'd like to know what the interface Comparable compares in Java.
Let's say I have two Nodes with only one instance variable each. How come node1.compareTo(node2) works?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code of `Node.compareTo()` and we can tell you what it compares.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29

Comment: `Comparable` is a generic `interface`, it compares types of the generic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is an interface, and as such it contains no logic. A concrete class with `implement Comparable` must implement the `.compareTo()` method, as detailed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

Implementing this interface means you intend the class to be able to compare itself with another instance, and return a numeric value representing if it should be considered "greater" or "less" than the instance passed in. This is often used with sorting in collections.

For example:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int compareTo(Node other) {
       return (this.id < other.id ) ? -1 : (this.id > other.id) ? 1 : 0;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
>   that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's
>   natural ordering, and the class's compareTo method is referred to as
>   its natural comparison method.

The [documentation of the compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Here is a sample :

```
public class MyComparable implements Comparable< MyComparable >{

   private int value;

   @Override
   public int compareTo( MyComparable other ) {
      return this.value - other.value;
   }

   public MyComparable( int i ) {
      value = i;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      MyComparable _12    = new MyComparable( 12 );
      MyComparable _42    = new MyComparable( 42 );
      MyComparable _12bis = new MyComparable( 12 );
      System.out.println( _12.compareTo( _42 ));
      System.out.println( _42.compareTo( _12 ));
      System.out.println( _12.compareTo( _12bis ));
   }
}
```

It ouputs:

```
-30
30
0
```

- -30 (<0) means 12 < 42, no surprise
- 30  (>0) means 42 > 12, ok
- 0   (=0) means 12 equals 12, seems correct